# Why does not entity framework use the like in this LinQ subquery?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, subquery

I am trying to get a string field of a tamble as result of a subquery in this way:

```
List<MyType> lstResult = dbContext.MyType
    .Where(x=>x.MyStringField.StartsWith(dbContext.MyType.Where(y=>y.ID == 123).MyStringField));
```

The where resulting is this:

```
WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX([Project2].[MyStringField], [Extent1].[MyStringField]) AS int)) = 1
```

But this does not use the like and give me results that is not correct.

However, if I use this query:

```
List<MyType> lstResult = dbContext.MyType
    .Where(x=>x.MyStringField.StartsWith("Abcd");
```

the where is this:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[MyStringField] LIKE 'Abcd%'
```

Why in the first case the query does not use the like? In other cases I use subqueries like that, although is using IDs (long type field) and the query os correct. Perhaps I miss something when the field is a string.

Thank so much.

Comment: How is this even compiling? `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not `T`.

Comment: What is "not correct"? I can't imagine that this returns incorrect results. What unexpected results do you get (when the LINQ query is syntactically correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this compiles because of the Where statement which is not even enumerated as "Where" method is a Deferred method which will not return any result till you enumerate it using a method like "Single, First, etc...".

Now, Change your request to be something like this:

```
// get the string that we want to check against.
var myStringField = dbContext.MyType.Single(y=>y.ID == 123).MyStringField; // <== you can use SingleOrDefault instead if you are not sure that the row is there, as this will throw exception if there is no MyType with id = 123.

List<MyType> lstResult = dbContext.MyType
    .Where(x=>x.MyStringField.StartsWith(myStringField)).ToList();
```

hope this help.